# How do I use LevelDB from Dart?

Tags: dart, leveldb

I'm looking into Dart for server-side development and one of the things I'd need to use if I went that direction was LevelDB. There is a port for the JVM that I could use from Java or Groovy but I haven't been able to find anything in Google that points me to a leveldb package for Dart.

I know it's possible to write a native port that uses the C++ API but I'm neither a C++ nor a Dart programmer so while that's theoretically possible, it's out of the question for me personally.

Since LevelDB and Dart are both Google initiatives, surely there's integration somewhere isn't there?

Comment: Are there specific features you need from LevelDB or would another similar key-value store fill your needs. There are some packages that seem to provide similar features but I don't know LevelDB and therefore can't tell.

Comment: I didn't see anything extant in the Dart ecosystem that matches the comprehensive functionality of LevelDB. It is a very good K/V store and has other desirable characteristics when dealing with asynchronous and event-based data.

Comment: I had the impression most packages are rather limited too. The best option would be probably MongoDb but that's probably very heavyweight compared to LevelDB.

Comment: Thanks for the info. MongoDB isn't an option I want to use for a number of reasons. The next likely candidate that gets closest to the feature set of LevelDB is probably Redis. The problem is that Redis' features are similar but the focus on memory-first or disk-first is a significant difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use LevelDB, which is written in C, you'll need to use the Dart VM's [native extensions](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/native-extensions-for-standalone-dart-vm/) API. At the time of this writing, there is no open source binding for LevelDB and Dart VM.

Thanks for the question!

Comment: Does that mean there is one, it's just not open source? I'd love to provide something like this to the community but I can't do it by myself. I don't have the C chops necessary to pull it off well. I could acquire them, I'm sure, but I'm not positive I have the time to go down that route. It may be I just have to wait until someone else provides one. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a LevelDB binding for Dart at https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/leveldb. Please try it out and file bugs for any issues you see.